# What is the overhead of constantly uploading new Textures to the GPU in OpenGL?

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics, 3d

What is the overhead of continually uploading textures to the GPU (and replacing old ones). I'm working on a new cross-platform 3D windowing system that uses OpenGL, and am planning on uploading a single Bitmap for each window (containing the UI elements). That Bitmap would be updated in sync with the GPU (using the VSync). I was wondering if this is a good idea, or if constantly writing bitmaps would incur too much of a performance overhead. Thanks!

Comment: Why render the ui client side?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well something like nVidia's Geforce 460M has 60GB/sec bandwidth on local memory.

PCI express 2.0 x16 can manage 8GB/sec.

As such if you are trying to transfer too many textures over the PCIe bus you can expect to come up against memory bandwidth problems.  It gives you about 136 meg per frame at 60Hz.  Uncompressed 24-bit 1920x1080 is roughly 6 meg.  So, suffice to say you could upload a fair few frames of video per frame on a 16x graphics card.

Sure its not as simple as that.  There is PCIe overhead of around 20%.  All draw commands must be uploaded over that link too.

In general though you should be fine providing you don't over do it.  Bear in mind that it would be sensible to upload a texture in one frame that you aren't expecting to use until the next (or even later).  This way you don't create a bottleneck where the rendering is halted waiting for a PCIe upload to complete.

Comment: It should be noted that plain glTexImage has the overhead of reinitializing the texture object. If performance matters one should use glTexSubImage; in the case of Pixel Buffer Objects glBufferSubData + glTexSubImage

Comment: Once you are saturating the bus does the CPU time of creating a new texture object really matter?

Comment: It may, because creating a new texture object requires at least 2 memory allocations (actually, more likely 3: one for the data structure, one for the bitmap in main memory, and one for the bitmap in gpu memory) before the transfer can even start. The latency of the transfer will not hide that overhead, it comes on top. Also, allocations must be synchronized not only across your application's threads, but across all threads on the system, since the memory is shared by everything, so I would not necessarily book the overhead in the "not noticeable" category.

Comment: @dm.skt:  Fortunately that latency can be hidden by loading textures into GPU before you need them...

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, your answer is going to be profiling. However, some early optimizations you can make are to avoid updating a texture if nothing has changed. Depending on the size of the textures and the pixel format, this could easily be prohibitively expensive.

Profile with a simpler situation that simulates the kind of usage you expect. I suspect the performance overhead (without the optimization I mentioned, at least) will be unusable if you have a handful of windows bigger, depending on the size of these windows.